# When using Capybara/Poltergeist, how to access application thread with pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, capybara, pry, poltergeist

I am running tests on a rails and emberjs application and have :js => true set on my tests.  I can drop a binding.pry in the spec and it pops open a REPL just fine, but if I drop a binding.pry in the app, the REPL will show up in the console, but the spec continues.  This, I believe, happens because with poltergeist as the driver, capybara runs the spec in one thread and the application in another thread.  Is there a way to set things up so that I can use binding.pry in the application code to open a REPL and pause both the app and the spec?

Here is an example of the binding.pry statement that works fine and the one that gets left behind:

Works:

employee_signs_in_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'
feature 'Visitor signs in', :js => true do
  scenario 'Success' do
    visit '/sign_in'
    sign_in_as(FactoryGirl.create(:employee, confirmed_at: Time.now))
    binding.pry
    page.should have_content('Example Content')
  end
end
```

Gets left behind:

sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  include Devise::Controllers::Helpers

  respond_to :json

  def create
    binding.pry
    # code for create action
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting... we successfully use `binding.pry` in both selenium and poltergeist driven specs with no issues. Can you provide a minimal code sample that can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ChrisCashwell, added some example code above, but not something you could easily reproduce it with; over the weekend when I have the time I'll create a basic ruby/ember app and put it on github for illustration purposes.

Comment: @ChrisCashwell Have you put the binding.pry in the application code as well as the spec files?

Comment: We can put the binding in either the spec or the implementation. No issues either way.

Answer (score 0):

Using pry in a forked process does not work.

You will need to use [PryRemote](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) to hook into another remote process.